# Better to use a macro definition or a pointer for a value in an array?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a fixed array of values that must be like it is since it is accessed that way with the communication protocol used (not relevant for the question), this way:

```
#define REGS_ARRAY_SIZE 256 
int16 Regs[REGS_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Each value has a specific purpose, for example:

```
Regs[ENABLE_MOTOR_ADDRESS]
```

will be used to indicate of a motor is enabled with a 0 or 1.

In order to use more comfortably these kind of values that has to be accessed from the code I write and from outside through the communication protocol I have thought that my options are:

To use a Macro:

```
 #define drive_enable (Regs [ ENABLE_MOTOR_ADDRESS ])
```

To use a pointer:

```
 int16 *drive_enable = &(Regs [ ENABLE_MOTOR_ADDRESS ]);
```

Is one of them better than the other? For me it looks more convenient to use the macro, as I avoid introducing the need to dereference every time I use the variable. However I never have good feelings towards the macros...

Any advise?

Comment: The macro approach seems fairly natural, though in that case I might prefer to write as `DRIVE_ENABLE`

Comment: You might as well use the same name ENABLE_MOTOR (Regs[ENABLE_MOTOR_ADDRESS])

Comment: The two are different things. One declares a variable the other does not

Comment: I don't need it being a variable _per se_, just use it in a friendlier way that Array[address]. If there is no issue in using a macro that is what I will do. I ask in case there is a better practice or a possible situation using a macro where it could lead to unwanted results, which is what I am afraid of. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: If you do not need to change the register which enable/disables the drive go for the marcos. It's less complex, though less error prone.

Comment: If I were doing it, I would use an `enum` to layout all the offset values,  That would result in all the access info located in one place (the enum).

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using functions:

```
int is_drive_enabled()
{
   return ( Regs [ ENABLE_MOTOR_ADDRESS ] == 1);
}

void enable_drive()
{
   Regs [ ENABLE_MOTOR_ADDRESS ] = 1;
}

void disable_drive()
{
   Regs [ ENABLE_MOTOR_ADDRESS ] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `return`s in the two bottom functions.

Comment: If the overhead of function calls is undesirable, they can be `inline`